# What are the implicit fields available in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Django provides a default `id` field for all the models in the `models.py`. Are there any other fields which are provided in the same manner? Where can I get the list?

A search on the internet did not help me.

Comment: Is there are problem you are trying to solve, or are you just asking because you are curious? There is no list of such fields, as it depends entirely on the model and relationships - django will also create tables implicitly. So, I ask again - why are you asking?

Comment: It is better to look at django's documentation www.djangoproject.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of database fields there is only `id` (which is the same as `pk` also), but in terms of class fields all models will inherit the `Model` class, which you can read its code on [django's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L354). Another quick way to know them is to run a django shell and check what the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) function gives you:

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>>
>>> class M(models.Model):
>>>     pass
>>>
>>> m = M()
>>> dir(m)

['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__',
'__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
'__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__',
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_base_manager', '_check_column_name_clashes',
'_check_field_name_clashes', '_check_fields', '_check_id_field', '_check_index_together',
'_check_local_fields', '_check_m2m_through_same_relationship', '_check_managers', '_check_model',
'_check_ordering', '_check_swappable', '_check_unique_together', '_default_manager',
'_deferred', '_do_insert', '_do_update', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD',
'_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta',
'_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_save_parents', '_save_table',
'_set_pk_val', '_state', 'check', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message',
'delete', 'full_clean', 'id', 'objects', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'save',
'save_base', 'serializable_value', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']
```

Note that these are methods and fields.